# Array Exception durning Array rotation of Copying array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am trying to leftRotation of an array. But after compilation  I am getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Here is my code :

```
public class MyTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, k;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        k = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print(n+" "+k);
        int inputArr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            inputArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        if(k > inputArr.length) {
             k=k%inputArr.length;
        }

        int[] result = new int[inputArr.length];
        System.arraycopy( inputArr, k+1, result, 0, k );
        System.arraycopy( inputArr, 0, result, k, inputArr.length-1 );

        itemPrint(inputArr);
        itemPrint(result);
    }

    private static void itemPrint(int[] inputArr) {
        for(int i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++){
            System.out.print(inputArr[i]+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

Here in `System.arraycopy( inputArr, k+1, result, 0, k );` I am getting error. Can anybody explain me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: the point where you are doing wrong is the most important part of your algorithm. If you are learning programming, or algorithms, or array rotation, you'll learn more effectively if you find the bug by yourself

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy( inputArr, k+1, result, 0, k );` is trying to copy elements of indexes `k+1` until `k+k` from `inputArr` into the array `result`.

If your `inputArr` (of size `n`) has a `length < k+k`, you'll naturally end up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

> Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>    - The srcPos argument is negative.
>    - The destPos argument is negative.
>    - The length argument is negative.
>    - srcPos+length is greater than src.length, the length of the source array.
>    - destPos+length is greater than dest.length, the length of the destination array.

I am not gonna give you the entire solution, I let you learn from your mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

4th parameter in the arraycopy function requires number of array elements to be copied. Here is a link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Just try to think what that could be changed to and you will get the answer.